# Not able to get log4net working to write to file

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, sharpdevelop

I am using sharpdevelop to create a console application in C#.  I have added in the reference for log4net and I added my logging statements while I was writing the code but I never looked at the log file.  Now I am done with the code I need to get the log file working.  My program runs fine, even the logging statements, but I can't find the log file.

I have tried to cobble together a couple of examples on getting log4net working.  I have the lines to read from the configuration and then to instantiate the object, these are the first lines in my program to run:

```
log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();
ILog datalogger = LogManager.GetLogger("myLog");  //initiate the data logger
```

Then in various places throughout the code I have this:

```
datalogger.Info(DateTime.Now.ToString() +  ":  using file: " + ProDirectory.ToString() + @"\" + myProFile.ToString());
```

I have also put the following in my app.config file:

```
<appender name="myLogAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender" >
    <file value="myLog.log" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%date %level - %message%n" />
    </layout>
  </appender>

  <logger name="myLog">
    <level value="All"></level>
    <appender-ref ref="myLogAppender" />
  </logger>
```

No matter what I do, I can't see the log file being produced.  I have changed the directory and even paused the program to see if I could find a handle open to the log file.  Each time I come up empty.  Not sure what I could be doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

not sure if this will help. I also had hard times making log4net work in different scenarios.

I use log4net root xml node to specify the appender.  hope it will help.

```
 <log4net>
<appender name="RollingFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
  <file value="log.txt" />
  <appendToFile value="true" />
  <rollingStyle value="Size" />
  <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
  <maximumFileSize value="250KB" />
  <staticLogFileName value="true" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%property{NDC}] - %message%newline" />
  </layout>
</appender>
<root>
  <level value="DEBUG" />
  <appender-ref ref="RollingFileAppender" />
</root>
```

UPDATE

You might also want to check Visual Studio output log. First setup the output log to log "ALL" (somewhere in VS settings). Then you should see exact error message of log4net in the output window of Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I have had issues with log4net creating the log file, it usually wound up being a file / directory permissions issue.

Change your `<file value="log.txt" />` to something that you know will be accessible by the current user / process running devhost.

For example: `<file value="%USERPROFILE%\Documents\log.txt" />` will create a log file in the user's My Documents folder. This is a folder that the user has permissions to write data to, and shouldn't give you any troubles with.

For more information on special folder values, see [this link.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_Folders)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I just had to clean up my XML a little, after I did the log file is working fine:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections> <!-- Level 1 -->
    <section name="log4net" 
      type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, 
            log4net"/> <!-- Level 2 -->
  </configSections>     
    <startup>
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0" />
    </startup>
<log4net>
  <appender name="myLogAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender" >
    <file value="myLog.log" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%date %level - %message%n" />
    </layout>
  </appender>
  <logger name="myLog">
    <level value="All"></level>
    <appender-ref ref="myLogAppender" />
  </logger>
</log4net>  
</configuration>
```